# SwiftUI Sample Data for Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a Core Data `XCDataModel` with entities that has `Codegen: Class Def.` set in Xcode, so I don't create the entities classes manually, but let Xcode generate it.

How do I provide sample data for preview in ContentView? Those examples I've seen provide a json-file, but they create the CoreData Object classes manually and makes them Codable, so if I want Xcode to auto generate the classes, how do I provide sample data?